# Definir tempo inicial de um Chonometer com o texto de um textView

Tags: java, android, textview

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível definir o valor inicial de um chonometer baseado em um textView.

[image: TextView em destaque]

texView que gostaria de definir o inicio do chronometer em destaque azul.

Essa textView recebe dados de um servidor, porém não é em tempo real, atualizando somente no OnResume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O valor que está no TextView é uma string que representa minutos e segundos.
Para usá-lo, como valor de início do Chonometer, tem de o converter para milissegundos.

Crie um método para a conversão:

```
private long minutesAndSecondsToMilliseconds(String minutesAndSeconds){
    String[] timeParts = minutesAndSeconds.split(":");
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]);
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]);
    return (minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000;
}
```

<sub>**Nota:** O método pressupõe que o valor na string `minutesAndSeconds` está no formato `mm:ss`. `mm` pode ser maior que 59.</sub>

Use depois assim:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
Chronometer chronometer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
...
...
long milliseconds = minutesAndSecondsToMilliseconds(textView.getText().toString());
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - milliseconds);
```

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente!! Obrigado!!

Comment: É possivel o chronometer passar dos 60 minutos?

Como o textView é um tempo de uma partida de futebol, ele vai até os 90 minutos, porém o chronometer quando passa de 60 ele "zera".

Comment: Não, de forma directa. Se passar os 60 minutos ele mostrará `1:00:00`. De forma indirecta pode usar um OnChronometerTickListener e no método `onChronometerTick()` pegar o valor actual do texto e alterá-lo para o formato que pretender.

Comment: Alterei o método de conversão para permitir valores maiores do que 59 minutos.

Comment: @LázaroRodrigues, a resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la ou necessita de algo mais?

Comment: Resolveu sim, muito obrigado!!

Só tem um problema, o cronômetro "recomeça" quando o item some da tela pelo scroll da recyclerview, tem uma maneira de não acontecer isso?

Comment: Tem, mas para isso é necessário ver o código. Faça outra pergunta.

Comment: Código do adapter ou da recyclerview?

Comment: Não posso ter a certeza mas o código do adapter deverá ser suficiente.